# How to add annotations and comments/replies using PDF Box

Tags: annotations, pdfbox

I am working on highlighting selected area in PDF document using PDFBox API and then adding conversations/replies against the highlight. The PDAnnotationTextMarkup() API is used for highlighting the selected text.

To add the conversations for this highlight, I have created one text annotation i.e PDAnnotationText() and one popup annotation i.e PDAnnotationPopup().

For text annotation, I have set the following attributes.

```
PDAnnotationText txtAnnot = new PDAnnotationText ();
   txtAnnot.setAnnotationName((UUID.randomUUID().toString()));          
   txtAnnot.setInReplyTo(highlightAnnot); // Reference to highlight annotation       
   txtAnnot.setName(PDAnnotationText.NAME_COMMENT);
   txtAnnot.setCreationDate((new GregorianCalendar()));             
   txtAnnot.setTitlePopup(userName);
```

For popup annotation, initialized following attributes.

```
 PDAnnotationPopup popAnnot = new PDAnnotationPopup ();
   popAnnot.setParent(txtAnnot); //Above text annotation
```

After adding the couple of conversations in the above pattern save the annotations and updated disk file. However, I could see the highlight, but not the added conversations in Acrobat Reader popup menu.

Do I need to set any other attributes to text and popup annotations, such as rectangle dimensions etc) ?

Please help me, if I miss any ste

Thanks in advance.
CM

Comment: Please have a look at the AddAnotations.java example in the source code download. If you still have problems, please update your question with the version you are using and include the improved code.

Answer (score 2):

```java
PDAnnotationTextMarkup markup =
      new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT);
markup.setContents(letterValue);
```

where `letterValue`(String Format) is the Value you want on pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had forgotten to add the annotations to the `PDPage` using `.setAnnotations()`.